# Getting a warning printing array object after it's modified in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a simple Perl module to create and manipulate a deck of cards. (I know such modules exist already; I'm doing it as an exercise.) The deck creates fine, and prints fine after it's first created. However, if I shuffle the deck, then printing the deck again generates a warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at Deck.pm line 23.
```

Here is the code, with Line 23 indicated by a comment:

```
sub new {
    my $classname = shift;
    my @suits = ("s", "h", "d", "c");
    my @pips = ("A", "K", "Q", "J", reverse 2 .. 10);
    my @deck;
    foreach my $suit (@suits) {
        foreach my $pip (@pips) {
            push (@deck, "$pip$suit"); 
        }
    }
    my $self = \@deck;
    bless($self, $classname);
    return $self;
} 

sub print_deck {
    my $self = shift;
    print join " ", @{$self};        # This is line 23
    print "\n";
}

sub shuffle {
    my $self = shift;
    my $i = @{$self};
    while ($i > 0) {
        my $j = int(rand($i));
        @{$self}[$i, $j] = @{$self}[$j, $i];
        $i--;
    }
}

1;
```

I have a test script that creates a new deck, prints it, shuffles it, and prints it again. The first print is fine, but the second print generates the warning shown above. Here is the test script:

```
my $deck = Deck->new;
print "The deck of cards looks like:\n";
$deck->print_deck;                # This print works fine

$deck->shuffle;
print "The shuffled deck looks like:\n";
$deck->print_deck;                # This print generates the warning
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `shuffle` method introduces an additional `undef` value inside the array ref. After `shuffle`, there is one more element:

```
my $before_shuffle = bless(
  [
    "As",  "Ks", "Qs", "Js",  "10s", "9s", "8s", "7s",  "6s", "5s",
    "4s",  "3s", "2s", "Ah",  "Kh",  "Qh", "Jh", "10h", "9h", "8h",
    "7h",  "6h", "5h", "4h",  "3h",  "2h", "Ad", "Kd",  "Qd", "Jd",
    "10d", "9d", "8d", "7d",  "6d",  "5d", "4d", "3d",  "2d", "Ac",
    "Kc",  "Qc", "Jc", "10c", "9c",  "8c", "7c", "6c",  "5c", "4c",
    "3c",  "2c",
  ],
  "Deck"
);
my $after_shuffle = bless(
  [
    "2d",  "6s",  "3s", "Qs",  "7s",  "7h", "7d",  "4c", "3c", "Jd",
    "Js",  "Qh",  "9s", "Kc",  "5d",  "2h", "5s",  "6h", "Ah", "8s",
    "7c",  "Qd",  "Qc", "3d",  "8c",  "Jh", "10c", "6c", "Jc", "9h",
    "9d",  "2s",  "4d", "4s",  "10d", "9c", "Kd",  "6d", "5c", "5h",
    "Ks",  "8d",  "Ad", undef, "As",  "8h", "3h",  "Kh", "2c", "4h",
    "10h", "10s", "Ac",
  ],
  "Deck"
);
```

It is happening in the very first iteration of your `foreach` inside `shuffle`.

```
my $i = @{$self}; # <-- this is the number of elements in the array
while ($i > 0) {
    my $j = int(rand($i));
    @{$self}[$i, $j] = @{$self}[$j, $i]; # <-- switch [52, rand] with [rand, 52]
    $i--;
}
```

`$i` will always by `52`. But you have indexes `0` to `51`. So the line where you shuffle will assign index `52` to index `$j` and vice versa. But index `52` was not set before, so it is `undef`. The solution is reduce `$i` by one to match `0` to `51`:

```
my $i = @{$self} - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. This definitely falls under the heading of "stupid mistake." It was an easy fix; I moved `$i--;` before `@{$self}[$i, $j] = @{$self}[$j, $i];` and voilà. `$i` does need to be 52 to begin with, to generate a random number between 0 and 51, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed. I did not even see the `$i--` line. Just used a debugger to step through it after I had discovered the `undef` with Data::Dump.

Comment: Could also use `$#{$self}` to get the last index of the array reference (it would be 51 in this case)